# Cannot Show Data and Pagination using Codeigniter (Error PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter for my application and I'm a newbie for this. I get several error from Codeigniter. I'm distracted with the variable error.

So, this is my Model:

```
class menuObjek extends CI_Model{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();

    }

    public function getWisata($perPage,$uri){
        $this->db->select("namaObjWisata, deskripsiObjWisata");

        $this->db->from("objekwisata");
        $this->db->order_by("kategori","ASC");

        $getData = $this->db->get("", $perPage, $uri);

        if($getData->num_rows() > 0){
            return $getData->result_array();
        }else{
            return null;
        };
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class showObjek extends CI_Controller {

private $data= array();



public function showObjek(){

    parent:: __construct();

    $this->load->model("menuobjek","", TRUE);
    $this->load->helper("url");
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library("pagination");

}

public function iniShow() {


    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("objekwisata");
    $getData = $this->db->get();
    $result = $getData->num_rows();

    //var $detail;

    $config["base_url"] = base_url()."index.php/showObjek/iniShow/";

    $config["total_rows"] = $result;
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $config["full_tag_open"] = "<p>";
    $config["full_tag_close"] = "</p>";

    $config["first_link"] = "&lt;&lt; First";
    $config["last_link"] = "Last &gt;&gt; ";


    $data["detail"] = $this->menuobjek->getWisata($config["per_page"], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data["pagination"]= $this->pagination->create_links();


    $this->load->view("menu_view", $data);
   }
}
```

The last is View:

```
                   //if(isset($detail)){
                    foreach($detail as $rows){

                        echo"

                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>
                                        <img src='#' class='img-rounded' />
                                        <p class='judul_objek'>".$rows['namaObjWisata']."</p>
                                        <article>
                                            ".$rows['deskripsiObjWisata']."
                                        </article>

                                    </a>
                                </li>

                            ";
                    }
                //}
```

This is showing these errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: detail
>
> Filename: views/menu_view.php
>
> Line Number: 124
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: views/menu_view.php
>
> Line Number: 124

I'm really confused. I have to fix this. Please, anyone help me.

Thank you.

Comment: try `print_r($data["detail"]);` after `$data["detail"] = $this->menuobjek->getWisata($config["per_page"], $this->uri->segment(3));` in Controller and check whether you are getting values or not

Comment: I don't get the value. I tried to var_dump($detail) and the result is null. @LimiJerin

Comment: try print_r( $this->db->last_query()); after $getData = $this->db->get("", $perPage, $uri);

Comment: still not working :( @JOELEE

Answer (score 0):

are you passing the third segment in the url. Because if you are not, then in the model it will result in null. And so the foreach will not find $details. I think you need to assign a default value for the first page case. That is, if uri segment 3 is not present, then it is first page and so the model should take something else as an argument instead of URI sergment 3

Comment: Yes, I'm passing it through the third segment. I think an errors occured when getting the data from database.

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
if(!preg_match('{^\d+$}',$uri)){ 
$this->db->limit($perPage); //first page
}else{
$this->db->limit($perPage, $uri);
}
$getData = $this->db->get();
//$getData = $this->db->get("", $perPage,$uri );
```

Answer (score 0):

`objekwisata` table may not contain any record that why `function getWisata` is returning null value in `detail` variable. And array much contain atleast one index for `foreach()` loop. Please check the records is present in the table or not.

Comment: I have checked it, and the records is present.